# dfittool results interpretation

Tags: matlab, distribution, probability

Does anyone know how to tell the difference between distributions (ie their goodness of fit) using the dfittool in Matlab? In a class I took forever ago, we learned about the log likelihood parameter and how to compare a pdf fitted to Gaussian vs gamma, etc. But right now, all the matlab help files online are like "it means something." Any assistance would be appreciated. Basically, I need to interpret the "results" in "edit fit" of the dfittool. I want to be able to compare my dfits to each other from the results, so I can pick the best fit for my analysis. I don't know what the difference is between a log likelihood of -111 vs -105.

Example below:

```
Distribution: Normal
Log likelihood: -110.954
Domain: -Inf < y < Inf
Mean: 101.443
Variance: 436.332
Parameter Estimate Std. Err.
mu 101.443 4.17771 
sigma 20.8886 3.04691
Estimated covariance of parameter estimates:
mu sigma 
mu 17.4533 6.59643e-15
sigma 6.59643e-15 9.28366
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

(Log) likelihood is a measure of the fit of a distribution to data, so the simple answer is: the distribution with the largest likelihood is the one that fits best. However, what you get here as an output is the *maximized* likelihood, i.e. the likelihood at those parameter values where it is maximal. Different families of distributions might be differently "flexible", so that it is easier to get a larger likelihood with one of them in general, so this limits comparability. This holds especially if you compare families with different numbers of parameters. A fix for this is to use formal model comparison, e.g. using the [Bayes factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor), which however is considerably more complex mathematically, or its approximation, the [Bayesian information criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion).

More generally speaking however, it is seldomly a good idea to just randomly pick distributions and see how well they fit. It would be better to have some at least partially theoretically motivated idea why a distribution is a candidate. On the most basic level this means considering its definition range: the normal distribution is defined on the whole real line, the gamma distribution only for nonnegative real numbers. This way it should be possible to rule one of them out based on basic properties of your data.